# R - How can I extract values inside a JavaScript object from the downloaded HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, r

I am doing web scraping using the package `rvest`, but I have difficulty to extract the information of a JavaScript object.

The JavaScript is in the form of:

```
... some js ...
var selectoptions = {
  "Region A": {
  "key" : "a",
  "defaultvalue" : "a",
  "values" : { //key : value
                    "(A01) A1": "a01",
                    "(A02) A2": "a02",
                    "(A03) A3": "a03",
                    "(A04) A4": "a04"
  }
 }, 
  "Region B": {
  "key" : "b",
  "defaultvalue" : "b",
  "values" : { //key : value
                    "(B01) B1": "b01",
                    "(B02) B2": "b02",
                    "(B03) B3": "b03",
                    "(B04) B4": "b04"
  }
 }
}
... some js ...
```

How can I extract the information (`"values"` of each region)?

Below is what I tried:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
url <- "http://www.census2011.gov.hk/en/constituency-area.html" #the url
js_code <- html(url) %>% html_nodes("script") %>% html_text()
js_code <- js_code[[9]] # The information I wanted is in the 9th element
info_wanted1 <- str_extract(js_code, "\\{.*?\\}")
info_wanted2 <- str_extract_all(js_code, "\\{.*?\\}")

> info_wanted1
[1] NA
> info_wanted2
[[1]]
character(0)
```

But it returns nothing. I suppose it will at least give me something embedded by `{` `}`. Did I make any mistakes? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the cleanest regex parsing I was able to construct:

```
js2 <- strsplit(js_code,  "value")  # first split on "value"
# Then remove the first item which preceded the first instance and work on the rest.

js3 <- lapply( js2[[1]][-1], function(tx) {
                                  regmatches(tx, gregexpr("value[^{]+\\}", tx) ) })
```

The `[^}]\\}"` portion of that pattern is a negated character-class and essentially says to return all the non-curley-brace characters before the first curley-brace following the text-`value`.

## ----

Earlier explorations:

First I assigned that text to  variable name, `txt`, but did not do so using a read-operations which would have broken it by line-breaks.

Your pattern does not match within that text:

```
> regmatches(txt, gregexpr("\\{.?\\n\\}", txt) )
[[1]]
character(0)
```

But slight modification of it does:

```
> regmatches(txt, gregexpr("\\{.+\\n\\}", txt) )
[[1]]
[1] "{\n  \"Region A\": {\n  \"key\" : \"a\",\n  \"defaultvalue\" : \"a\",\n  \"values\" : { //key : value\n                    \"(A01) A1\": \"a01\",\n                    \"(A02) A2\": \"a02\",\n                    \"(A03) A3\": \"a03\",\n                    \"(A04) A4\": \"a04\"\n  }\n }, \n  \"Region B\": {\n  \"key\" : \"b\",\n  \"defaultvalue\" : \"b\",\n  \"values\" : { //key : value\n                    \"(B01) B1\": \"b01\",\n                    \"(B02) B2\": \"b02\",\n                    \"(B03) B3\": \"b03\",\n                    \"(B04) B4\": \"b04\"\n  }\n }\n}"
```

Since regular expressions are generally "greedy", the algorithm found the first match and then went as far as it could to match everything up to and including the last curley-brace.

To defeat the greediness of regex you first need to split into separate character vector elements by an appropriate delimiter and I picked the string: `values`:

```
> js2 <- strsplit(js_code,  "values")
> js3 <- lapply( js2[[1]], function(tx) {regmatches(tx, gregexpr("\\{.+\\}", tx) ) })
> js3[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "{\r\n\t\t //create a bubble popup for each DOM element with class attribute as \"text\", \"button\" or \"link\" and LI, P, IMG elements.\r\n\t\t $('.link-1').CreateBubblePopup({\r\n  position : 'top',\r\n  align : 'center',\r\n  innerHtml: 'Terms and Definitions',\r\n  innerHtmlStyle: {\r\n\t\t\t  color:'#FFFFFF', \r\n\t\t\t  'text-align':'center',\r\n\t\t\t  'padding':'5px'\r\n\t\t\t },\r\n  themeName: 'all-black',\r\n  themePath: 'images/jquerybubblepopup-theme'\r\n });\r\n\t\t $('.link-2').CreateBubblePopup({\r\n  position : 'top',\r\n  align\t : 'center',\r\n  innerHtml: 'Data Dissemination Events',\r\n  innerHtmlStyle: {\r\n   color:'#FFFFFF', \r\n   'text-align':'center',\r\n   'padding':'5px'\r\n  },\r\n  themeName: \t'all-black',\r\n  themePath: \t'images/jquerybubblepopup-theme'\r\n });\r\n $('.link-3').CreateBubblePopup({\r\n  position : 'top',\r\n  align\t : 'center',\r\n  innerHtml: 'Download 2011 District Council Electoral Boundaries Index Map',\r\n  innerHtmlStyle: {\r\n   color:'#FFFFFF', \r\n   'text-align':'center',\r\n   'padding':'5px'\r\n  },\r\n  themeName: \t'all-black',\r\n\t\t\t\tthemePath: \t'images/jquerybubblepopup-theme'\r\n });\r\n  });\r\n  $(document).ready(function(){\r\n\t  var options = {\r\n\t\t\t\tpreselectFirst : \"hki\",\r\n\t\t\t\tpreselectSecond : \"a01\",\r\n\t\t\t\temptyOption: false,\r\n\t\t\t\temptyValue: 'Please Select',\r\n\t\t\t\temptyKey: '-'\r\n }"

> js3[[2]]
[[1]]
[1] "{ //key : value\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A01) Chung Wan\": \"a01\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A02) Mid Levels East\": \"a02\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A03) Castle Road\": \"a03\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A04) Peak\": \"a04\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A05) University\": \"a05\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A06) Kennedy Town & Mount Davis\": \"a06\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A07) Kwun Lung\": \"a07\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A08) Sai Wan\": \"a08\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A09) Belcher\": \"a09\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A10) Shek Tong Tsui\": \"a10\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A11) Sai Ying Pun\": \"a11\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A12) Sheung Wan\": \"a12\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A13) Tung Wah\": \"a13\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A14) Centre Street\": \"a14\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(A15) Water Street\": \"a15\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B01) Hennessy\": \"b01\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B02) Oi Kwan\": \"b02\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B03) Canal Road\": \"b03\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B04) Causeway Bay\": \"b04\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B05) Tai Hang\": \"b05\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B06) Jardine's Lookout\": \"b06\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B07) Broadwood\": \"b07\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B08) Happy Valley\": \"b08\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B09) Stubbs Road\": \"b09\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B10) Southorn\": \"b10\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(B11) Tai Fat Hau\": \"b11\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C01) Tai Koo Shing West\": \"c01\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C02) Tai Koo Shing East\": \"c02\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C03) Lei King Wan\": \"c03\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C04) Aldrich Bay\": \"c04\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C05) Shaukeiwan\": \"c05\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C06) A Kung Ngam\": \"c06\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C07) Heng Fa Chuen\": \"c07\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C08) Tsui Wan\": \"c08\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C09) Yan Lam\": \"c09\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C10) Siu Sai Wan\": \"c10\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C11) King Yee\": \"c11\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C12) Wan Tsui\": \"c12\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C13) Fei Tsui\": \"c13\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C14) Mount Parker\": \"c14\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C15) Braemar Hill\": \"c15\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C16) Tin Hau\": \"c16\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C17) Fortress Hill\": \"c17\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C18) Victoria Park\": \"c18\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C19) City Garden\": \"c19\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C20) Provident\": \"c20\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C21) Fort Street\": \"c21\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C22) Kam Ping\": \"c22\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C23) Tanner\": \"c23\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C24) Healthy Village\": \"c24\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C25) Quarry Bay\": \"c25\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C26) Nam Fung\": \"c26\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C27) Kornhill\": \"c27\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C28) Kornhill Garden\": \"c28\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C29) Hing Tung\": \"c29\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C30) Sai Wan Ho\": \"c30\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C31) Lower Yiu Tung\": \"c31\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C32) Upper Yiu Tung\": \"c32\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C33) Hing Man\": \"c33\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C34) Lok Hong\": \"c34\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C35) Tsui Tak\": \"c35\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C36) Yue Wan\": \"c36\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(C37) Kai Hiu\": \"c37\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D01) Aberdeen\": \"d01\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D02) Ap Lei Chau Estate\": \"d02\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D03) Ap Lei Chau North\": \"d03\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D04) Lei Tung I\": \"d04\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D05) Lei Tung II\": \"d05\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D06) South Horizons East\": \"d06\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D07) South Horizons West\": \"d07\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D08) Wah Kwai\": \"d08\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D09) Wah Fu I\": \"d09\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D10) Wah Fu II\": \"d10\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D11) Pokfulam\": \"d11\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D12) Chi Fu\": \"d12\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D13) Tin Wan\": \"d13\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D14) Shek Yue\": \"d14\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D15) Wong Chuk Hang\": \"d15\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D16) Bays Area\": \"d16\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"(D17) Stanley & Shek O\": \"d17\"\r\n  }\r\n }"
```

You will then need to "clean up" by trimming the unnecessary stuff from the leading and trailing portions of those blocks, and it turns out, removing at least the first item which doesn't really look like one of the tables you wanted.